# Easy conditional probability

Tags: probability

I roll a fair six-sided dice. If my result is less than $2$, I get a $20\%$ chance to win a prize. If it's not less than $2$, then I get a $10\%$ chance to win a prize. What's $P($I win a prize)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see, your reasoning is correct and your conclusion is correct. I don't know why your answer might have been marked as wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Seems correct.

Perhaps the question is asking for exact form.

$$\frac1{30}+\frac1{12}=\frac16\left( \frac{1}{5}+\frac12 \right)=\frac{7}{60}$$